# Minecraft will not launch from eclipse for mod testing purposes

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

As a CS Student, I was trying to do something with Java so I decided to make a Minecraft mod, following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_qM-Z0IQ4k tutorial. At around 13:10 he opens Minecraft from eclipse, but whenever I try to do it, it gives me a few errors.

The first one that I've "fixed" was that the java.library.path did not contain lwjgl64. I fixed it by downloading lwjgl from https://www.lwjgl.org/download and following these instructions. http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Downloading_and_Setting_Up_LWJGL
For the native library location I pointed it towards the folder with the extracted lwjgl.zip in it. (I am including this part because I may have done something wrong at this stage but am unsure of it.)

Now that that problem was fixed, the problem arose that I could not launch as there we no recent launches so I found THIS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGGV6G3pPB4 video which showed how to get eclipse to do that, and it worked!... except that my class doesn't have a main method in it.

Sorry if my wording/explanation is jumbled - basically, how do I get eclipse to launch Minecraft with the mod loaded? I have installed all prerequisites.

Here is my "main class" below.

```
package com.gmail.nameredacted.magicmirror;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;


import com.gmail.nameredacted.magicmirror.init.MagicMirrorItems;
import com.gmail.nameredacted.magicmirror.proxy.CommonProxy;

@Mod(modid = Reference.MOD_ID, name = Reference.NAME, version = Reference.VERSION)
public class MagicMirror 
{
    @SidedProxy(clientSide = Reference.CLIENT_PROXY_CLASS, serverSide = Reference.SERVER_PROXY_CLASS)
    public static CommonProxy proxy;
    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event)
    {
        MagicMirrorItems.init();
        MagicMirrorItems.register();
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
    {
        proxy.registerRenders();
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, your question is kind of a jumble.  You should clearly state only the current problem you're trying to solve, and explain what you've already done to debug _this_ issue.  On the surface it sounds like you want to launch the Minecraft engine with your mod linked in.  You'll have to explain how the Minecraft engine gets configured so that it includes your mod code, and show the configuration file/parameters you are using.

Comment: @Jim Garrison Sorry if I was unclear! I wanted to get Minecraft to launch but by using the run option in eclipse it was giving me the lwjgl error so I added that part in because it was originally part of the problem. :( The current issue is that  Minecraft won't launch because there is no main method, despite it working in the video tutorial without a clear explanation of how to launch it (around 13:10).

Comment: There is no main method in your code, and you should not be attempting to launch your code directly.  You'll need to figure out where the Minecraft engine's main method is and launch that.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. It seems that someone else had the same issue as me, http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/modification-development/2574505-cant-run-minecraft-from-eclipse, and what I did was that I went to Run -> Run Configurations and clicked on Java Applications. For the Project I chose my current project file, and for the Main Class I typed in "GradleStart" and it worked.